# Is there any way to modify the following Spark Python code for better usage of memory.

Tags: python, memory-management, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I am trying to run the following code. It gives me a GC error. I tried running this without reduceByKey and the code works. I guess it is taking a lot of memory in the reduce function. I tried increasing driver memory, number of cores, executor memory. Also I tried groupByKey instead of reduceByKey. But no luck.

But what I understand is that I am doing something wrong in not freeing the variables. Can some one help me.

```
        import os
        import sys
        import unicodedata
        from operator import add 

        try:
            from pyspark import SparkConf
            from pyspark import SparkContext
        except ImportError as e:
            print ("Error importing Spark Modules", e)
            sys.exit(1)


        # delimeter function
        def findDelimiter(text):
            sD = text[1] 
            eD = text[2] 
            return (eD, sD) 

        def tokenize(text):
            sD = findDelimiter(text)[1]
            eD = findDelimiter(text)[0]
            arrText = text.split(sD)
            text = ""
            seg = arrText[0].split(eD)
            arrText=""
            senderID = seg[6].strip()
            yield (senderID, 1)


        conf = SparkConf()
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

        textfile = sc.textFile("hdfs://my_IP:9000/data/*/*.txt")

        rdd = textfile.flatMap(tokenize)
        rdd = rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
        textfile=""
  rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://my_IP:9000/data/total_result503")
    rdd=""
```